# How to select an element under a table row based on another element under it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select the checkboxes based on the link with the delete.jpg. I have tried this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><input id="cbox1" type="checkbox"></input></td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td><a href="www.example.com"><img src="delete.jpg" alt="Delete"></img></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td><input id="cbox2" type="checkbox"></input></td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td><a href="www.example.com"><img src="delete.jpg" alt="Delete"></img></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
var x = window.content.document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox' img[alt='Delete']");
```

Sadly, it is wrong and I think it is reading as the image is under the input.

What I need is to determine the ID of the checkbox if that row has a delete.jpg image. Remember that the img is enclosed in a link.

Any approach will be helpful but I need this on javascript. jQuery is also a possibility. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are multiple `checkboxes` what do you need?

Comment: Removed tags that the OP doesn't want answers for

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by placing a click handler on the `a` element that wraps the `img`. From there you can use the `this` keyword to reference the clicked element, then `closest()` to get the parent `tr` and finally `find()` to get the checkbox.

Also note that your HTML has a couple of errors; `<img>` and `<input>` tags are self closing, and do not require `</img>` or `</input>` tags, respectively. Try this:

```js
$('table a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link behaviour
  
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var $checkbox = $tr.find(':checkbox');
  
  console.log($checkbox.prop('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><input id="cbox1" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td><a href="www.example.com"><img src="delete.jpg" alt="Delete"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td><input id="cbox2" type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td>some info here</td>
    <td><a href="www.example.com"><img src="delete.jpg" alt="Delete"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is this very easy on jquery? :) Thanks!! But is there an answer in pure javascript?

Comment: Sure, but why did you tag the question with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue
$("img[alt='Delete']").parent().parent().parent().find("input")

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery's magic:

```
    $('img[src="delete.jpg"]').each(function(){
      var e = $(this);
      var id = e.closest('tr').find('input').attr('id');
      console.log( e, id );
    });

// To store the id in image element:
    window.id_list = [];

    $('img[src="delete.jpg"]').each(function(){
      var e = $(this); // image element
      var id = e.closest('tr').find('input').attr('id');
      e.data('myid', id);
      id_list.push(id);
    });

    // to access
    $('img[src="delete.jpg"]:first').data('id');
    // or
    console.log(id_list);
```

Comment: Sorry for a silly question but how do I use the variable "id" outside of the function?